# How to create tagadelic page in view?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

How can I create a **[Tagadelic](http://drupal.org/project/tagadelic) page** in a view? I create a tagadelic page in a view, but all tags display as a column.  See the below screenshot

[image: all tag display style as a column]

But I want to display them in the following style:

[image: i want to display as following style:]

Would you please tell me, how to change this style?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the field and then click on REWRITE RESULTS and check off the box strip HTML which will strip out all the html that is creating a line break between each tag. If you need more control you can use "Rewrite the output of this field" and wrap your field in its own element.